# Problema com a utlização de float em vetor C/C++

Tags: c, c++, tipagem

Eu preciso fazer o seguinte problema em C:

Ler 12 notas válidas de alunos e armazená-las em um vetor notas. Admitindo-se que pode haver erros no processo de digitação, alguns valores armazenados no vetor podem ser inválidos, isto é, fora do intervalo entre 0.0 e 10.0. Determinar e apresentar a quantidade de notas inválidas digitadas e a média das notas válidas.

Pelo problema o vetor precisa ser `float`, porém ao digitar o valor é atribuído o 0 ao invés do valor digitado na posição que está sendo lida.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main(){
    //declara as variaveis --> notasval(quantidade de notas validas), soma(soma das notas validas)
    float  media, notas[12], soma=0;    
    int notasval=0, i;

    for(i=0;i<12;i++){
        scanf("%f", &notas[i]); //Lê as notas 
        if(notas[i]>=0.0 && notas[i]<=10.0){ //verifica se as notas estão no intervalo valido (entre 0 e 10)
            notasval = notasval + 1; //soma +1 ao contador notasval caso a nota for valida
            soma = soma + notas[i]; //executa a soma das notas validas para depois fazer a média
        }
        printf("\t%d", notas[i]);//Eu estava usando essas 3 linhas para printar as variáveis
        printf("\t%d", notasval);
        printf("\t%d\n", soma);
    }
    media = soma/notasval; //faz a média

    printf("A quantidae de notas invalidas é: %i\nA média das notas validas é: %.2f\n", 12-notasval, media); //mostra os resultados
}
```

A primeira linha de zeros é o valor de vetor, a linha do meio é a quantidade de notas validas, e a ultima linha era pra ser a soma das notas validas:
[image: resultado]

Comment: Você está imprimindo `soma` (e `notas[i]` também) com `%d`. Então o `printf` está tentando interpretar os bytes de `soma` (e `notas[i]` também) como se fosse um inteiro. O correto seria imprimir com `%f` para `float`

Comment: O enunciado é ambíguo, então fica complicado resolver de forma adequada.

Comment: mdss, nem tinha percebido kkkkkkkk, mto obrigado

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O enunciado é ambíguo por isso não é um bom problema para resolver. Ele fala em entrar 12 notas válidas, depois admite que entre essas 12 pode ter algumas inválidas. Mas fazendo de conta que não tem esse problema existe um erro de formatação do da apresentação do dado. Assim fica mais organizado e correto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float notas[12], soma = 0;    
    int notasval = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        scanf("%f", &notas[i]);
        if (notas[i] >= 0.0 && notas[i] <= 10.0) {
            notasval++;
            soma += notas[i];
        }
    }
    printf("A quantidae de notas invalidas é: %i\nA média das notas validas é: %.2f\n", 12 - notasval, soma / notasval);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mOvmMV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Gradesc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Grades.c).

Tirei a impressão de cada passo entrado porque o enunciado não pede isto. Se ele está ali por razões de depuração não vejo vantagem em mantê-lo agora. Tirei os comentários porque eles são óbvios , redundantes e alguns com interpretação equivocada do que acontece ali, um dos motivos que é melhor não comentar, só tem uma coisa pior que código sem comentários, um código com comentário inúteis e errados.

Se está usando C não tem porque falar em C++, talvez não saiba, mas são linguagens bem diferentes que tem algumas coisas compatíveis.

Comment: mto obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @AriSbardelotto veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.